# Get iOS 6 Beta still develop iOS5

Tags: xcode, iphone-developer-program

If I put ios 6 beta on my iphone can I still develop and submit updates for my app on ios 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What iOS version you put on your phone doesn't matter. The important thing is, that you can only submit apps using a non-beta version of XCode (the one on the Mac App Store). You can't submit an app to the App Store using the beta version of XCode that is available on the developer portal (and which you need to develop iOS 6 apps) along with iOS 6.

Comment: So are you saying I can put iOS 6 beta on my phone without getting the beta of xcode? I don't understand how I'm supposed to test the new beta but still remain an active developer.

Comment: I've installed iOS 6 on my secondary device and I don't have the beta XCode as I don't yet intend to develop for iOS 6. You just download the iOS 6 beta, and use iTunes to install it (Option-Click the Restore button). **IMPORTANT**: You can't revert your iPhone back to previous OS versions if you install iOS 6 beta.